In which, or all of the following situations does a raise of a no trump bid constitute a Blackwood call?
Opener bids one club, responder bids one heart. Opener rebids 2NT (18-19 high card points, balanced). Responder raises to 4NT. I take that to be a "quantitative" bid, aiming for 6NT. The reason is that no suit has yet been agreed upon and 4Nt is actually a raise of 2NT. Am I right?
Opener bids one heart, responder bids 2NT (Jacoby, 13-15, four hearts). A opener's "raise" to 4NT IS Blackwood, because "2NT" was really a "raise" of hearts, not a true no trump bid. Is this correct?
Opener bids one heart, responder answers 4 diamonds (splinter), and opener bids 4NT. This is Blackwood because the splinter bid is (de facto) a raise of the heart suit, right?

If you limit Jacoby responses to 13-15 HCP, how should partner respond to 1H with QJTx KJxx AQJ Kx?

@ruds: The equivalent response would be 3 NT.

So when slam is more likely you like to take up more space in the auction? That seems... bad.

You have correctly identified that the first 4NT is quantitative and the other two are Blackwood. However, I must caution you against falling into the trap mentioned by the Hideous Hog in Victor Mollo's Swings and Arrows:

Don't fall into the common error of assuming that the average player invokes Blackwood to inquire about aces. Aces are purely coincidental. Blackwood is primarily an emotional outlet. The message is: I'm excited. I have a splendid hand and you sound pretty good. Let's go places! Whoopee! Four notrumps!

First of all, Jacoby 2NT is not typically limited to 13-15 HCP. Usually responder is unlimited, and so you should only jump to Blackwood because the number of aces will allow you to place the contract in 5, 6, or 7 hearts. A typical hand would be x AKJxxx KQJxx A. You are safe at the five level; if partner has one ace you will make 6; and if partner has both missing aces, you will make 7. A hand like Axx KQJxx AJx Kx is not suitable for a jump to Blackwood despite its 18 HCP. If partner holds xxx Axxx Qxxx AQ, the five-level is too high. On the other hand, if partner holds Kx Axxxx Kx Axx, 7 is a laydown (assuming opening leader doesn't hold an 8-card side suit allowing an opening ruff). Don't think that asking for kings on the last hand is right, either, since they could hold Kxxx Axxx Kxx Ax, putting you on a finesse for 12 tricks.
On the splinter hand, responder is again unlimited. If you hold x KQJxxx Axxx AK, you can call Blackwood because you have 5-level safety and the missing aces will tell you which level to play at. But with a less distributional hand, the location (and quantity) of partner's filler cards will be important to determine the correct level.

On the splinter hand, something like Kx KQJxxx xxx AK is perhaps slightly more likely as a hand to bid Blackwood.

There are some borderline auctions, and some where different partnerships will go different ways (and sometimes, different partners in the same partnership!)  But standard(1) is:

When opener has bid NT naturally, 4♣ is Gerber, 4NT is quantitative.  Note: this is extended by many to "first and last (natural) NT" - if the first "real" bid was NT (even if there's bidding after) or the last bid was NT, then Gerber/quantitative applies.
When there is a known 8-card fit, 4NT is Blackwood (likely keycard of some sort).
If neither apply, a jump to 4NT is Blackwood (arguments on keycard need to be had with the partnership)
If both apply, you had better have an agreement.  This is where most partnership disagreements show up (and where some players thing "4♣ is Gerber and 4NT is Blackwood."  Find a better solution to this one!)

The ACBL's new Alert Procedures define an "Opening No Trump Sequence"; it's a good way of discussing "first NT".
So yes, as others have mentioned, you have got it right in your three cases.  One, there's no fit, and NT was bid naturally by opener; 4NT is quantitative (and 4♣ would be Gerber, even though opener started with 1♣.  If you have a problem with that, find another solution - common in my area is "the only non-GF response to 2NT is 'pass'."  So your "agree clubs, slam try" call is 3♣)
The other two are not just de facto heart raises, they are by agreement heart raises.  They happen to be heart raises that show something else as well, but that's irrelevant to the "izzet Blackwood" question, over the fact that they promise a heart fit.
As always, your agreements in some odd auctions will depend on your other agreements.  For instance:

1NT-2♦; 2♥-4NT is quantitative with 5 hearts if you play Texas transfers; to RKC in hearts, you go 1NT-4♦; 4♥-4NT.
1NT-2♣ 2♥-? Do you have a call that agrees hearts and is forcing? If so, do that, and after doing that 4NT is Blackwood (don't do it and 4NT is quantitative, probably with 4 spades.  4♣ is Gerber, again, probably with 4 spades).  If you don't, then just assign meanings with partner.
it's worse with 2NT-3♣; 3♥-?  What do you do with a 4=5 black hand with slam-going values?  How do you set hearts, and keycard?  Luckily, this is rare; unluckily, it is common in the rare cases when one partner has half the deck.

"Auctions that start with a natural NT bid" are hard to completely define, if you "always want an ace-ask".  However, as ruds has mentioned, players - especially lower-level players (2) - over-ace-ask, or too-soon ace-ask.  Mostly it's ruds' Mollo quote, my paraphrase of which is: "4NT says 'hey partner, we might have slam!'  And 4♣ is better because we can still get out in 4♠ if partner doesn't agree!"; but a lot of it is just "I don't know how to get the information I need for slam" (or "I don't know the information I need for slam").  You can tell these pairs by the long time it takes to bid 5, or 6, of the trump suit after the "we're missing one ace" Blackwood response - they're concerned they might be off cashing AK.(3)
The other phrase I use for this (which I'm sure I cribbed off one of hundreds of experts) is: "Remember, Blackwood (and Gerber) is not a way to get to good slams.  It's a way to stay out of bad slams" where you can take 14 of the last 11 tricks after they cash both their aces.  As such, to bid it you need to have enough knowledge to commit to bidding 6 if you're off one ace/keycard.  If you're not yet ready to commit, you need to find another way to explore.
All of that is over your specific question of course, which accurately defines the three sequences.
(1) note that I'm a bit of an iconoclast.  I play "Gerber is baby food" (or "No Gerber Ever") if I get a choice.  Costs me maybe one time in two years; just stopping my partners from bidding Gerber and forcing them to actually describe their hand (or the actual, useful meaning for 4♣ in the sequence) has saved me that half-board maybe monthly.  I'm describing standard here.
(2) but a National-level expert I play with occasionally has Gerbered 3 times, and at least twice was wrong to do so (or at least should have done something else first).
(3) this answer is intended as a player answer, but from a directing standpoint, look up "Hesitation Blackwood" for the problem that arises when partner understands the problem and fixes it for the pause-5 bidder.

Ruds has given an excellent answer explaining why you ought not to bid 4NT after an unlimited Jacoby 2NT or a splinter. Nevertheless, should you choose to ignore his advice, I for one would take your 4NT bids exactly as you defined them - quantitative over a no trump sequence, Blackwood if a suit has been agreed.
